# How to Perform Animation in Matplotlib alongside a Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, animation

I would like to change the circle color every 0.25 seconds through a thread, and showing the result live through `matplotlib` animation. Here is my code (I don't even understand why the animation is not performed):

```
import threading
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def apply_color_shift(fig, circle):

    def func():
        for i in range(100):
            circle.set_fc((i/100, 0, 0, 1))
            time.sleep(0.25)
            print("something")
    anim = threading.Thread(target = func)

    def do_nothing(frame):
        print("ANIM")
        fig.show()
    FuncAnimation(fig, do_nothing, frames = [0.1*i for i in range(100)])

    anim.start()
    plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('square')

c = Circle(xy = (0, 0), color = "red")
ax.add_patch(c)
ax.set_xlim([-50, 50])
ax.set_ylim([-50, 50])

fig.show()
apply_color_shift(fig, c)
```

What is the problem here, and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you running this in interactive mode? In that case the problem would be that since `plt.show()` does not block, the function returns and no reference to `FuncAnimation` is left, such that it is garbage collected. Outside of interactive mode the code by itself runs fine. Not sure what the threading is used for though.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest have tried without threading and use only animation, the problem know is that it is slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color every 0.25 seconds, that should be the interval of the animation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('square')

c = Circle(xy = (0, 0), color = "red")
ax.add_patch(c)
ax.set_xlim([-50, 50])
ax.set_ylim([-50, 50])

def change_color(i):
    c.set_fc((i/100, 0, 0, 1))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, change_color, frames = range(100), interval=250)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that. But why is it very slow? (Not smooth)

Comment: The speed is determined by the `interval`. As I understood it, you want it to be changing every quarter of a second (=250 ms); but of course you can put a lower interval to have the animation run more smoothly.

Comment: The problem is also that if I set `interval = 0.5` etc (less than 1), then the animation does not do anything.

Comment: I thought that using a `Thread` would help to smooth the animation

Comment: You cannot go below 1 ms interval.